# Turning on linker flags with CMake

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, linker, cmake

When generating VS2010 targets with CMake, I would like the /LTCG flag turned on (only for release + releasewithdebinfo if possible, but its okay if its on for debug builds). How do I modify the linker flags? `add_definitions()` doesn't work because that only modifies compiler flags. And yes, I have wrapped it in if(MSVC).

How do I modify the linker flags?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can modify the linker flags in MSC using #pragma comment(linker, ...)

However, if you'd like to do it in the build process with cmake, here are the names you need to know:

- `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS`
- `CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS`
- `CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS`

(Thanks to [Cmake.org](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2006-October/011517.html)).

Comment: In recent CMake versions the only flag left is CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS; the best thing to do is to edit the target properties (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783932/how-to-add-linker-or-compile-flag-in-cmake-file)

Comment: I don't know why the comment above has two upvotes. See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/variable/CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS.html?highlight=cmake_shared_linker_flags and https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/variable/CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS.html?highlight=cmake_module_linker_flags : these flags are definitely in recent CMake versions.

Answer (score 4):

and STATIC_LIBRARY_FLAGS
http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#prop_tgt:STATIC_LIBRARY_FLAGS

for static libraries

Answer (score 3):

For adding linker flags - the following 4 CMake variables:

```
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS
```

can be easily manipulated for different configs (debug, release...) with the [ucm_add_linker_flags](https://github.com/onqtam/ucm#ucm_add_linker_flags) macro of [ucm](https://github.com/onqtam/ucm)

linker flags can also be managed on a per-target basis - by using [target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html) and passing flags with a `-` in front of them (but not with a `-l` - that would be treated as a link library and not a link flag).

Answer (score 3):

The use of the "ucm" library seems like a nice approach.  I rolled a simple macro that help me uniformly manage linker flags in CMake for all configurations while also allowing compiler-specific use. (Just setting the variable can cause flags to stack up when CMake is configured multiple times.)

```
macro(ADD_MSVC_LINKER_FLAG flag)
    if(MSVC)
    if(${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} MATCHES "(${flag}.*)")
        # message("skipping linker flags")
    else()
        set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${flag}" CACHE STRING "Linker Flags for Release Builds" FORCE)
    endif()

    if(${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} MATCHES "(${flag}.*)")
        # message("skipping linker flags")
    else()
        set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} ${flag}" CACHE STRING "Linker Flags for Release Builds" FORCE)
    endif()

    if(${CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS} MATCHES "(${flag}.*)")
        # message("skipping linker flags")
    else()
        set(CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS} ${flag}" CACHE STRING "Linker Flags for Release Builds" FORCE)
    endif()

    if(${CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS} MATCHES "(${flag}.*)")
        # message("skipping linker flags")
    else()
        set(CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${flag}" CACHE STRING "Linker Flags for Release Builds" FORCE)
    endif()
    endif()
endmacro()
```

Other compilers are then supported by creating a compiler-specific macro that checks for the compiler to be in use.  That makes it harder to set the right flag on the wrong compiler.

```
if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
```

and

```
if(${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID} STREQUAL Clang)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add linker flags for a specific target using the `LINK_FLAGS` property:

```
set_property(TARGET ${target} APPEND_STRING PROPERTY LINK_FLAGS " ${flag}")
```

(note that I added a space before the flag since I'm using `APPEND_STRING`)