# Using JNI with Qt

Tags: qt, java-native-interface

There is, with Qt 5.6, a simple way to call Java methods in a Qt application : [Android extras](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtandroidextras-index.html). As one may guess, this simple way is limited to the Android platform.

Is there a way to write my application such as it is multiplatform(1) and can use JNI calls to Java methods ?
Moreover, is there a simple way ? I mean Android extras provides an environment and an API that let me concentrate on coding what my application do. I do not waste time in looking for a way to interface both native and JVM worlds, trying to solve platform dependent problems.

There has been a similar question asked : [How can I deploy a mixed C++/Java (JNI) application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120694/how-can-i-deploy-a-mixed-c-java-jni-application)

(1) By multiplatform, I mean IOS, Linux, Windows in addition to Android.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answere, but an idea:

You could try to take the `QtAndroidExtras` source code and try to build it on windows/linux/... I don't know if it's even possible, you probably have to modify the pro file, but I think it's worth a try.

The interesting part seems to be this `.pri` file:

```
<path_to>\Qt\<version>\Src\qtandroidextras\src\androidextras\jni\jni.pri
```